# External Accessory unknown when plugged in since boot

Tags: iphone, objective-c, external-accessory

I am developing an app the uses an external accessory (and am using the EAAccessory framework). Everything works great, except for the instance when the iDevice powers on while the accessory is plugged into the dock. It recognizes the accessory for a short time -- usually 10-15 seconds, then a "EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification" is sent for my accessory, and right after a "EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification" is sent with an "unknown" device. When I ask what accessories are connected, I get the following output:

> " {\n 
>   connected:YES\n 
>   connectionID:0x825600\n  name: \n 
>   manufacturer: \n  modelNumber: \n 
>   serialNumber: \n  firmwareRevision: \n
>   hardwareRevision: \n  protocols:
>   (\n)\n  delegate: (null)\n}"

So, it can tell that something is connected, just not the device that is connected. If you have an accessory, you can test this easily using the [EADemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010079-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this accessory approved in Apple's MFi program?

Comment: Yeah, although testing the problem with a different accessory seems to work so it may be an issue with the accessory...

Comment: hi Ned, i am also using EAAccessory framework for connect my accessory but i am not getting any notification after connect the Accessory to iPhone. have you any idea please tell me,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a faulty cable and it worked with a different cable.

Answer (score 0):

You get the EAAccessoryDidDisconnectNotification then immediate EAAccessoryDidConnectNotification when your accessory transfers from the un-authenticated to the authenticated state. If your EAAccessory object is empty after that, then you haven't made that transition. This works for my accessory so you will have to inspect the traffic between the accessory and the iOS device to see what error you get.